# db2 stored procedure format

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2, squirrel-sql

I'm using db2 and SQuirreL SQL

I'm trying to create a stored procedure with a simple select statement inside of it. When I omit the select statement in the following below and run the code, the procedure is created. Also this procedure can be dropped and called.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure
    LANGUAGE SQL
    BEGIN

    END
```

When I add in the select statement, I get Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-102, SQLSTATE=42601,...

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE test_procedure
    LANGUAGE SQL
    BEGIN
        SELECT column_name FROM table_name
    END
```

If you go to [IBM iseries information center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/html/as400/v4r5/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafymstnegcodes.htm) is says:

SQL0104 SQLCODE -104   SQLSTATE 42601

Explanation: Token &1 was not valid. Valid tokens: &2.

Comment: Are you deleting your comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that I wasn't given the right permissions to execute the stored procedure. [SQL0551N](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21381783) This link explains more about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The statement terminator in SQuirreL is called "Statement separator" and it can be defined in:

Menu Session > Session Properties... > tab SQL > at the end of the SQL square, the option Statement Separator.

[image]

This is valid in version 3.5.3